# SQL: Mapping first (or random) result of element from specific column matching certain conditions in another column to variable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The problem is as follows:  I want to query a database, and return the number of hits that have particular values in two different columns, grouped by timestamp window.  I am currently doing this successfully with the following query:

```
SELECT shortdate, 
sum(column1 like '%interestingthing1%') thing1count, 
sum(column1 like '%interestingthing2%') thing2count,


FROM (
select LEFT(string(DATE), 8) shortdate,column1
from [database]
where column3 like '%thingthatcolumn3shouldbe%'
)
group by shortdate

ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

What I want to also do is to also return a variable which is a random element of column2, corresponding to a row that satisfies the thingthatcolumn3shouldbe, one for each interestingthingn (n=1,2,...).

I have some intuition that this can be done either with some user-defined function (I am doing this in google bigquery, which allows javascript functions), or a whole mess of UNIONs within the FROM (...) statement above.  But since I am far from a SQL expert, this question is partially an effort to start using some best/better practices early on.  Naked opinions welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the query below. It will pick the "first" value for `column2` when `column1` satisfies your condition, but since order of values going into aggregation function is not deterministic - it is as good as random. And since `FIRST` aggregate function ignores `NULLs`, we just need to make sure to convert `column2` to `NULL` when condition isn't met.

```
SELECT shortdate, 
  sum(column1 like '%interestingthing1%') thing1count, 
  sum(column1 like '%interestingthing2%') thing2count,
  first(if(column1 like '%interestingthing1%', column2, NULL)) column2forthing1,
  first(if(column1 like '%interestingthing2%', column2, NULL)) column2forthing2
FROM (
  select LEFT(string(DATE), 8) shortdate, column1, column2
  from [database]
  where column3 like '%thingthatcolumn3shouldbe%'
)
group by shortdate

ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1000
```